# How can I produce a bar-graph-like plot with truncated bars?

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, plot, graph

Suppose I have two lists.
I extracted min, max lists from original 2dim list.

Looping original list, I extracted list. Extracted list has values -100s and min of list

For example, From [0, 0, 1, 3, 10] list, return [-100, -100, 0].

In here, the number of -100 is representing the number of min values(In this example, the number of 0s) in the list. And 0 is min value of list.

```py
original = [ [0, 0, 1, 3, 10], [4, 2, 2, 5, 10, 15], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 10] ...]
min = [-100, -100, 0, -100, -100, 2, -100, -100, -100, -100 0, ...]
max = [-100, -100, 10, -100, -100, 15, -100, -100, -100, -100, 10, ...]
```

With this list, I want to draw bar graph like below.
[image: bar graph]

If meet -100, pass that time. If not, Draw bar from min to max.

Also I want to give a different color with criteria.

I couldn't find good example from [matplotlib example page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/index.html) , or from search result in google.

Can I get tips for this?

Comment: Please don't name your variables `min` and `max`, This disables the possibility to call the functions with the same name.

Comment: matplotlib's `bar` has a `bottom` argument!

Comment: @JohanC Sure, I named that list min, max because of showing example. Thank you  point that :) I'll never name like that in my code.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Oh my god... Thank you. It's my fault. I've never thought to find `bar`'s argument... just looked for type of graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code achieves the desired result using [matplotlib's colourmap](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

min_vals = [-100, -100, 0, -100, -100, 2, -100, -100, -100, -100, 0]
max_vals = [-100, -100, 10, -100, -100, 15, -100, -100, -100, -100, 10]
colours = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]

w = len(min_vals)
h = max(max_vals) - min(x for x in min_vals if x != -100)

arr = np.ones((h, w), dtype="int")

for i, vals in enumerate(zip(min_vals, max_vals)):
    if -100 not in vals:
        arr[vals[0]:vals[1]:,i] = np.array([colours[i]]*(vals[1]-vals[0]))

cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['white', 'green', 'red'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))

ax.imshow(arr, cmap=cmap)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.yticks(range(h))
plt.xticks(range(w))
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This is what I really want. Thank you. It works well :)